# The server didn't receive response from Facebook Webhook

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, postman, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I'm trying to integrate webhook into my project, I have verified the webhook successfully, but when I send sample data to the server, my server does not receive anything, my project developed on Codeigniter.

I tried using postman to post Json data to the webhook url that was authenticated, my server received

Postman: [POST] https://xxxxxx.xxx/api/webhook

[RAW]

```
{
  "field": "conversations",
  "value": {
    "page_id": 4444444,
    "thread_id": "t_mid.14833205540:9182a4e489"
  }
}
```

Code:

```
public function webhook(){

    if (isset($_GET['hub_mode']) && isset($_GET['hub_challenge']) && isset($_GET['hub_verify_token'])) {
        if ($_GET['hub_verify_token'] == 'EcyUykjnmredclnuYFLShBKHfutRFfDRdfdfb'){
            echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
        }
    }

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input",true);
    $myfile = fopen("./my-assets/uploads/text.txt", "w");
    fwrite($myfile, $data);
    fclose($myfile);

    http_response_code(200);
}
```

Comment: Sending test data from Facebook does not work, or your own attempt using Postman? Do you see incoming POST requests in the access log? What does the error log say?

Comment: hi, I tried, my server doesn't show logs when sending test data from facebook, only log of the get method verify

Comment: @colinmorgan Did you get the response. I m having same issue.